# IE11 CSS bug with clear:right - how to workaround?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float, internet-explorer-11

I'm looking for a workaround for this odd IE bug (present in IE11, haven't tested other versions, works perfectly in Chrome/FireFox).

CSS clear:right; doesn't work as expected with rtl language even though clear:left; for an ltr language works without problems.

It's best to show an example so I'll attach screen shots.
[image: English version - no problem]
[image: Hebrew version - see the bug]
[image: Chrome and FireFox present it fine]

I've noticed problems similar to this one all around so any general workaround would be most welcome. I'm not trying to solve it only specifically for this page.
Thanks

The English page: http://colnect.com/en/coins/coin/48962-50_Dollars_XXVIII_Olympic_Games_Athens_2004-Numismatic_Product-Bimetallic_Silver_-_Gold-Australia

The Hebrew page: http://colnect.com/he/coins/coin/48962-50_Dollars_XXVIII_Olympic_Games_Athens_2004-Numismatic_Product-Bimetallic_Silver_-_Gold-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94

Comment: Stupid question, but would `clear:both` be an option? If so, I wouldn't waste too much time thinking about IE bugs and just get it over with.

Comment: clear:both isn't an option as it'll ruin how the rest of the page looks like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lack of an IE 11 I can only test this in IE 10, but the problem presents there as well.

Adding `width:100%` and `overflow:hidden` to the `.ibox` element does seem to fix it – then it won’t need clearing any more, because it will go underneath the floated content before it since there is no place for it beside it any more.

See if that’s a workaround you can make use of.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I find it odd that it works but it does. Another workaround I came up with that seems to work is to add a clear:right to everything under that <div>, so basically adding a clear:right to the <p> itself would fix it as well. Odd enough, but oddity's been IE's legacy AFAIR.

Answer (score -1):

1. Could you please **create a reduced example** demonstrating the problem?
2. I checked the code and there is no `float: right` box before (prior in source code) to the cleared `<div class="ibox" xid="48962">`.

Sorry! there are! **.i_d dt {float: right}** are floated right. So you are quite possibly right with your query and claims.

1. Note that you are using invalid attributes in your XHTML 1.1 page.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This should have been a comment, you don’t answer the question. I know that you cannot post comments yet, but still, the rules should not be broken. But thanks for trying to help anyway!

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to deepen my research into it as I prefer to fix it and move on. As Palec wrote though, this isn't an answer though...